# How can I get just the enum names from a Java file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, osx

Enum files in java can get messy in structure, I'm trying to get Just the Enum names

```
...
import com.mckesson.dex.model.activityLog.concreteFactory.ModifiedPropertyYesNoFactory;

public enum OrganizationActivityLogItemType implements IActivityLogItemType<OrganizationActivityLog>, DisplaysAs
{

    @Deprecated GENE_VARIANT_PUBLIC( "Gene Variant/Mutation/Allele", null ),

    VARIANTS_MUTATIONS( "Variants/Mutations/ Alleles/Loci/Probes", ALFactory.PUBLIC_PRIVATE ),
    CATEGORIES( "Categories", null ),
    PUBLIC_VISIBLITY_COVERED_WHEN_MEETS_NECESSITY_CRITERIA( "Covered - When Meets Medical Necessity Criteria",
                                                            ALFactory.PUBLIC_PRIVATE ),
    PUBLIC_VISIBLITY_NOT_COVERED_INVESTIGATIONAL(
        "Not Covered - Investigational",
        ALFactory.PUBLIC_PRIVATE ),
    PUBLIC_VISIBLITY_NOT_COVERED_NOT_MEDICALLY_NECESSARY(
        "Not Covered - Not Medically Necessary",
        ALFactory.PUBLIC_PRIVATE ),
...
```

This is close-ish, but I feel like it could probably be done better.

`awk '{ print $1 }' My.java | grep -v '^"' | grep -v '^ALFactory' | sed -e 's/(//'`

How can I get just the Enum names from an enum file using unix cli tools?

solutions need to be portable to OS X at least, as that's my working environment, though I would prefer that it also work on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script in `perl` that does it. Doing it just piping commands in the command line is either not possible or not maintainable. A naive approach would be

```
perl -npe 's/\b|\s+/\n/g' < My.java | grep '^[A-Z]\+_[A-Z_]\+'
```

but the script below is better:

```
#!perl -w
my $content = do { local $/; <> };
my @tokens = split /\b|\s+/, $content;
my $n = 0;
my $skip;

foreach (@tokens) {
    $n++; $skip = 0;
    next if /\s+/;
    next if /"/ ... /"/;    # skip strings
    next if /\(/ .. /\)/;   # skip parameters
    next if /@/ .. /^\w+$/; # skip annotations
    $skip ||= 1  if $n == 1 .. /\benum\b/; # skip from beginning to enum
    $skip ||= 1  if /enum/ .. /\{/; # skip to open bracket
    next if $skip;
    last if /\}/;

    print $_, "\n";
}
```